# Copy a Non-contiguous Range From Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, range, union

I have the following Code and I only want the Ranges that are given, but every time I use my Macro, the range C28 to H28 is also copied and pasted into the word-file.

This the Code that selects the ranges:

```
Dim rangeSP As Range 
Set rangeSP = Sheets("Details").Range("C27:H27") 

Dim rangeSP2 As Range 
Set rangeSP2 = Sheets("Details").Range("C29:H30") 

Dim rangeSpecification As Range 

Set rangeSpecification = Union(rangeSP, rangeSP2)
```

This where it gets copied and pasted into the word file:

```
wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute "Where it will be put"

wordApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

rangeSpecification.Copy 

wordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
```

I want to copy Tables from an Excel into a Word-File. So, I tried it with Union Ranges, because there are Rows in-between the Data Sets that I don't need. But when I use my Macro, the unwanted rows are also copied and pasted into the word file.

Comment: Either your method of copy/pasting the data doesn't like the combined range or your program is behaving incorrectly. I tried your code and it worked for me as written (I didn't transfer to Word, just pasted to another Excel sheet).

Comment: You are asking A but your code shows B. Please provide a [mcve] of your problem with sufficient code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Do you mean that `Range("C28:H28")` is also included? Please, show us, at least, the copying code, even if it looks logic (for us)...

Comment: This the Code that selects the ranges:

Dim rangeSP As Range
    Set rangeSP = Sheets("Details").Range("C27:H27")
    Dim rangeSP2 As Range
    Set rangeSP2 = Sheets("Details").Range("C29:H30")
    Dim rangeSpecification As Range
    Set rangeSpecification = Union(rangeSP, rangeSP2)

This where it gets copied and pasted into the word file:

wordDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute ""
    wordApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    wordApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
    rangeSpecification.Copy
    wordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False

Comment: in "", I am searching for the place where it should be pasted, but this works perfectly fine

Comment: Please, do not show code in comments! Edit your question and show THERE  the eloquent code...

Comment: Oh my Mistake, I put it in the Answer section

Comment: Soooooooo, everything is in the question now. needed a bit :)

Comment: Any merged cells in the ranges being used?

Comment: I checked, there are no merged cells that are uses

Comment: Yes, was just checking myself - you get a specific error message when there's merged cells - "we can't do that to a merged cell" when trying to copy.

Comment: You can't copy-paste a non-contiguous range from Excel to Word *manually*, so likely what you want to do is not supported.  You could paste to another sheet first, and then copy from there to Word.

Comment: Does someone have an idea for this problem. When my tables get pasted into the word document and there are already the ones there from the previous usage of the macro. How do I get rid of them. Can I add something to the vba code, so that the older tables get deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying and pasting multiple ranges (non-contiguous) can be tricky. Pasting such ranges within Excel sheets will be as expected. However, pasting across applications (Word or PowerPoint) will include the skipped cells.

For your situation, you have two options:

- Paste the multiple Excel ranges onto unused range on ative sheet or a new Excel sheet. Then copy the consolidated range and paste into Word.

```
    rangeSpecification.Copy ActiveSheet.Range("AA1")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("AA1").CurrentRegion
    rngData.Copy
    wordApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
    rngData.Clear
```

- Using VBA code in Word to delete the unwanted in-between rows after pasting from Excel. (Assuming there is only one table in Word document.)

```
ThisDocument.Tables(1).Rows(2).Delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. The method with pasting it in unused cells works great. You can just record the macro whilst pasting the cells and look at the code afterwards. Then you just need to put the rest back in and adapt it.